# Creating breakpoint in Xcode for unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

Is it possible to set the breakpoint in Xcode to have the debugger stop **only** on unrecognized selector?

I have other exceptions that are triggering, and I only want to trigger on the `unrecognized selector` exception, nothing else.

Comment: You may know this already, but be sure you know that although exceptions can trigger when you're debugging a project, they should never trigger in shipping code. Unlike some other languages, Objective-C exceptions are considered programmer error and your code should definitely not be triggering them as part of the normal flow of the app.

Comment: @Rob I heard this before. But then read the docs on exception handling.  They didn't really make them out to be such bad things.  So I should rely on explicitly returning values of problems?  Just curious, why's that?

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html), in particular the big box labelled "Important". You should use the [`NSError` handling pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806) instead. One of the main reasons is that exceptions are very expensive operations in the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Setting a symbolic breakpoint for `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` should do the trick.

In Xcode 4, press `cmd`+`6` to go to the Breakpoint Navigator, then click the `+`and choose "Add Symbolic Breakpoint…". Configure.

Comment: Be sure to enter in the entire `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` or it won't work and you will be confused (as I was.)

Comment: @zekel what do you mean with enter in the entire `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`?

Comment: @PeterWarbo I just meant that you should literally enter this entire string `-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` , not just the selector `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`, etc.

Comment: this definitely worked for me! my bug was subtle: wrote ````@selector(foo)```` instead of ````@selector(foo:)````

Comment: It is nicely [described here](http://www.fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2012/08/quick-and-easy-debugging-of-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance/)