# Objective-C parsing JSON NSNULL error, location not shown

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am parsing quite a large JSON model, and I have a LOT of objects set up to handle all the data. I recently added more data to the JSON model, to test it out, and I am getting this error

```
-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaed678
```

However, I need to know EXACTLY which function is crashing in order to fix it, but for some reason, xCode does not tell you where the function crashes which seems very odd, as that is very important information if you want to rectify the bug. Is there anyway for me to find out exactly which method or function caused the application to crash?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on unrecognized selector:

[Creating breakpoint in Xcode for unrecognized selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156090/creating-breakpoint-in-xcode-for-unrecognized-selector)

Then trace back in the code.

Comment: Wish I had known about this before, would have saved me a lot of hassle!! Cheers