# How to solve this issue "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f6f400"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

​Hello, when I run the application with simulator, the Xcode debug window shows some informations like this below:

**

```
2014-07-08 17:52:35.726 Overdue[10937:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8ce0990 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-07-08 17:52:35.764 Overdue[10937:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x955f040
2014-07-08 17:52:35.767 Overdue[10937:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x955f040'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x017f41e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x015738e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2 CoreFoundation 0x01891243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3 CoreFoundation 0x017e450b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4 CoreFoundation 0x017e40ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5 Overdue 0x00004543 -[CCViewController taskObjectAsAPropertyList:] + 99
6 Overdue 0x00003d1b -[CCViewController viewDidLoad] + 667
7 UIKit 0x0035233d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
8 UIKit 0x003525d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
9 UIKit 0x0037d509 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
10 UIKit 0x006c4e3c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
11 UIKit 0x00279c22 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
12 UIKit 0x00279646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
13 UIKit 0x00279518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
14 UIKit 0x002795a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
15 UIKit 0x0027863a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
16 UIKit 0x0027859c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
17 UIKit 0x002792f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
18 UIKit 0x0027c8e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
19 UIKit 0x00356b77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
20 UIKit 0x00272474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
21 UIKit 0x002725ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
22 UIKit 0x0027286b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
23 UIKit 0x0ef97587 -[UIWindowAccessibility(SafeCategory) _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 77
24 UIKit 0x0027d3c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
25 UIKit 0x0022dbc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
26 UIKit 0x00232667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
27 UIKit 0x00246f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
28 UIKit 0x00247555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
29 UIKit 0x00234250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
30 GraphicsServices 0x037e9f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
31 GraphicsServices 0x037e9a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
32 CoreFoundation 0x0176fca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
33 CoreFoundation 0x0176f9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
34 CoreFoundation 0x0179a68c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
35 CoreFoundation 0x017999d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
36 CoreFoundation 0x017997eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
37 UIKit 0x00231d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
38 UIKit 0x00233f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
39 Overdue 0x0000343d main + 141
40 libdyld.dylib 0x01e3b701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**

So what's going on with that? I tried to went to simulator and clicked Reset Content and Settings... it worked, after that I added the task to my tableView on the simulator, then I ran the application again, that informations appeared again. It actually drives me crazy. So what is the solution? Looking forward to your early reply. THX.

Comment: You've called a method on a class that doesn't support that method (i.e. `[someDictionary title]`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156090/creating-breakpoint-in-xcode-for-unrecognized-selector

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks! Found the issue with your comment! Silly mistake!

Comment: probably you dictionary ha not such property / method as `title`.

Comment: The problem is clearly line 99 in CCViewController.  Why did you not at least include that line in your question???  And why did you not Google "unrecognized selector"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the method `title` on `NSDictionary` class. Since you have not posted the code, I guess somewhere when you are returning a custom type of your class, its returning a dictionary instead.

```
[myCustomClassObj title]; // myCustomClassObj is referring to a Dictionary instead of your CustomClass
```

To figure out where the crash occurs add an exception breakpoint. It will halt at the exact line which is causing your app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

2014-07-08 17:52:35.764 Overdue[10937:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x955f040

This means you are trying to call a method or a property called title on an object of type NSDictionary, you think it's of some custom type you created, Book e.g. so maybe if you are storing the data locally or getting it from a web service and parsing a PLIST or JSON files, then check your parsers, they might be returning NSDictionary objects instead of Book or whatever it's the class you created