# Objective-C + WKWebkit Unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I'm pretty new to Objective-C/iOS Dev as a whole and am going grey over this. I can not seem to get WKWebkit working for the life of me.

After extensive Google Searches, I finally put together some code that compiles - buuuut the app crashes.

WebView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Webkit/Webkit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface WebViewController: UIViewController <WKUIDelegate>;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView *webView
@end
```

WebView.m

```
@implementation WebViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (NSClassFromString(@"WKWebView")) {
        _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    } else {
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    }
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
@end
```

I do have the class set as WebViewController under custom class in the storyboard, as well.

Here is the error message I keep getting:

```
[WebViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdbb570e050
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? I'm still too unfamiliar to catch any obvious bugs myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint for the error? I may give some additional context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156090

Comment: I had not - thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error says is that your class `WebViewController` does not have a method `superview`. Unfortunately I can not see the issue in the code you posted and assume it is somewhere else. Although the code itself is still very iffy.

You could use [exception breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802942/526828) which should show you exact line that is causing this and add that information.

In general I can assume that you are somehow using your class in place of `UIView`. An `UIViewController` is not a subclass of `UIView` so it does not have a method `superview`.