# Could not load NIB in bundle with name 'SecondViewController'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push the Navigator Controller to a different view controller but I keep getting the error saying the nib bundle name can't be loaded. Here's the code I'm using:

```
SecondViewController *vc1 = [[SecondViewController alloc]
      initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SecondViewController class]) bundle:Nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the name of the nib file, not the class name:

```
// Assuming there is a properly set up SecondViewController.xib in your project.
SecondViewController *vc1 = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
                            initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using Storyboards, you have to load your GUI a bit differently:

```
UIStoryboard *sboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardFileName" 
                                                 bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *vc1 = [sboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: I've tried just doing that but I still get the error. Here's the entire error: 2012-09-15 20:07:45.127 Passdata.app[4010:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/2BFE10F0-1513-44FE-AD99-7E928C739E9C/Passdata.app> (loaded)' with name 'SecondViewController''
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Is there a SecondViewController.xib in your project and added to your target?

Comment: I'm using a storyboard so I don't have a xib file, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: that fixed that problem but I'm also passing a string to the SecondViewController so I'm getting this error now, would you know anything about it?: 

2012-09-15 20:28:10.942 Passdata.app[4083:907] -[UINavigationController setTmpString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d57f530
2012-09-15 20:28:10.946 Passdata.app[4083:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setTmpString:]: unrecognized selector sent

Comment: Do you research before asking? I can't debug your whole app... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861626/how-to-resolve-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622865/how-do-i-debug-an-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-problem

Comment: Yeah, I looked up my error but I couldn't find any results. Most things came up were completely irrelevant.

Comment: @StørmShadøws, The error is saying that you're trying to call setTmpString on UINavigationController -- you should be calling it on SecondViewController